# How to create custom layout attributes in LayoutAttributesForDecorationView?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

Because I needed to change the background color of my decoration view I created a subclass of `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`. The only thing I'm missing is to create the layout attributes. This is what I currently do in `layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:atIndexPath:`:

```
public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes LayoutAttributesForDecorationView (NSString kind, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    CustomCollectionViewLayoutAttributes attribute = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes.CreateForDecorationView (kind, indexPath) as CustomCollectionViewLayoutAttributes;
    // ...
}
```

but it crashes with `System.NullReferenceException`, because `layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:withIndexPath:` returns null.

Am I missing something?

I tried it with

```
CustomCollectionViewLayoutAttributes attribute = CustomCollectionViewLayoutAttributes.CreateForCell<CustomCollectionViewLayoutAttributes> (indexPath);
```

but here I get

> UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist

The correct method should be something like

```
CustomCollectionViewLayoutAttributes attribute = CustomCollectionViewLayoutAttributes.CreateForDecorationView<CustomCollectionViewLayoutAttributes> (indexPath);
```

but it doesn't compile.

> No overload for method 'CreateForDecorationView' takes '1' arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the correct method:

```
CustomCollectionViewLayoutAttributes attribute = CustomCollectionViewLayoutAttributes.CreateForDecorationView<CustomCollectionViewLayoutAttributes>(kind, indexPath);
```

I should use the IntelliSense feature the next time before asking the question ...